# How do I achieve Google Maps like ActionBar view with ActionSherlock?

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, android-actionbar, spinner

What I need to achieve:

- A custom spinner like [this layout](http://sites.google.com/site/file3273/home/image/1.png)
- Activate an option in this spinner may direct the user to a swipe tab view like in [this layout](http://sites.google.com/site/file3273/home/image/2.png) (OFFLINE - STARRED - RECENT tabs)

What I managed to achieve:

- [Custom spinner](http://sites.google.com/site/file3273/home/image/3.png) like google map. But I couldn't uses `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS`

  ```
      ActionBar bar = this.getSupportActionBar();
  bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
  bar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

  MyCustomAdapter a2 = new MyCustomAdapter(this,
          R.layout.mainmenu_dropdownfull, string,
          Constants.dropdown_title, 
          Constants.dropdown_icon,
          Constants.dropdown_description);
  MyOnNavigationListener mNavigationCallback = new MyOnNavigationListener();
  bar.setListNavigationCallbacks(a2, mNavigationCallback);
  ```
- [Swipe tabs](http://sites.google.com/site/file3273/home/image/4.png) but it does not look like what I need: the spinner is below the tabs.

  ```
      ActionBar bar = this.getSupportActionBar();
  bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
  bar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
  bar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
  bar.setCustomView(R.layout.bar_customview);
  mViewPager = new ViewPager(getApplicationContext());
  adapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager ); //this is my custom class, extended from FragmentPagerAdapter
  mViewPager.setAdapter( adapter );
  mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener( adapter );
  mViewPager.setId( 0x7F04FFF2 );

  adapter.addTab( "Tab 1", BusRouteInfoFragment.class, TestFragment.createBundle( "Fragment 1 bus") );
  adapter.addTab( "Tab 2", TestFragment.class, TestFragment.createBundle( "Fragment 2") );
  adapter.addTab( "Tab 3", TestFragment.class, TestFragment.createBundle( "Fragment 3") );
  ```

How would I achieve a layout like Google map?